# compile gcc in AIX 7.1

Tags: gcc, compilation, aix

I create a library:

```
cat extprocsh.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> void sh(char *); int sh2(char *); void sh( char  *cmd ) {
        int num;
        num = system(cmd); } int sh2( char  *cmd ) {
        int num;
        num = system(cmd);
        return num; }
```

In Linux compiles is success and all is works:

```
gcc -fPIC -c extprocsh.c

gcc -shared -static-libgcc -o extprocsh.so extprocsh.o
```

**How to compile in AIX 7.1?**

Comment: What error message did you get when tried the same command in AIX?

Comment: When i try command linux, I do not have errors, but the library does not work.

Comment: One possible reason: if your Oracle server is of 64-bit (which is likely) then your extproc/plugin has to be compiled with flag '-maix64'

Comment: Or you might have realized that this plugin/extproc would be the greatest security hole ever.